# How to get the max datetime for particular date among multiple dates, data example is as below

Tags: sql, oracle, max, informatica, informatica-powercenter

Table has this value:

| Heading 1 | Heading 2 |
| --- | --- |
| xyz | 01-APR-2022 12.11.21.000000000 AM |
| xyz | 01-APR-2022 12.11.29.000000000 AM |
| xyz | 01-APR-2022 12.12.21.000000000 AM |
| xyz | 02-APR-2022 12.09.21.000000000 AM |
| xyz | 02-APR-2022 12.11.21.000000000 AM |
| xyz | 02-APR-2022 12.22.21.000000000 AM |

need below output:

| Heading 1 | Heading 2 |
| --- | --- |
| xyz | 01-APR-2022 12.12.21.000000000 AM |
| xyz | 02-APR-2022 12.22.21.000000000 AM |

Comment: Can you please specify which SQL (database and version) you are using, and the date column type (text/date) also?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It is Oracle DB

Answer (score 1):

informatica only solution -

1. Create an exp transformation with three ports.

```
in_out_Heading1
in_out_Heading2
out_date_trunc=TRUNC(in_out_Heading2)
```

2. Next, use an agg transformation  with below ports.

```
in_out_Heading1  --group by port
in_Heading2
in_date_trunc --group by port
out_Heading2=MAX(in_Heading2)
```

And then connect out_Heading2 and in_out_Heading1 to your final target.

Answer (score 0):

You can group by extracted date value, so need a conversion such as the one below

```sql
SELECT heading1, MAX(heading2)
  FROM t
 GROUP BY heading1, TRUNC(heading2)
```

the above SELECT statement is based on the Oracle database, you can replace `TRUNC(heading2)` depending on your current DBMS. *The data type of `heading2` is presumed to be `TIMESTAMP`*